# Store blob as a file in S3 with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, blob

I am using a file upload plugin in Vue to upload some image and pdf files through an API and it has an option to [create a blob field](https://lian-yue.github.io/vue-upload-component/#/en/documents#instance-file-fileobject) when uploading the files.

The request sent to Laravel is as follows. I can access the blob from the browser by copying and pasting the URL on the browser.

[image: blob array]

On the Server side code, I am trying to save the file with the following code but the saved file is some corrupted 64byte file rather than the actual image. How would we store the blob as a normal file in the filesystem?

```
if ($request->has('files')) {
        $files = $request->get('files');

        $urls = [];
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = 'files/' . $file['name'];

            // Upload File to s3
            Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename, $file['blob']);
            Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($filename, 'public');

            $url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);
            $urls[] = $url;
        }

        return response()->json(['urls' => $urls]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing this:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename, $file['blob']);
```

with this:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename, base64_decode($file['blob']));
```

Comment: Still the same issue unfortunately!

Comment: did you get a solution for this? if yes, can you share it please?