# Get image from blob Laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

First of all, this is the start of where I am at as a similar post
[Store blob as a file in S3 with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725247/store-blob-as-a-file-in-s3-with-laravel)

I am sending a photo from VueJS to Laravel. It is coming as multipart/form-data.

Vue Code:

```
export default {
  emits: ['onClose'],
  props: ['isOpen'],
    data: function() {
    return {
      serverOptions: {
        process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error) => {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append(fieldName, file, file.name);
          axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/chat/room/upload',
            data: formData,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
          })
          .then(() => {
            load();
          })
          .catch(() => {
            error();
          });
        }
      },
      files: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleFilePondInit: function () {
      console.log('FilePond has initialized');
      // example of instance method call on pond reference
      this.$refs.pond.getFiles();
      console.log(this.$refs.pond.getFiles());
    },
  },
```

Laravel Controller:

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{
    // This is what this is SUPPOSED to do. Grab the file from the frontend
    // Bring it here. Store it in S3, return the path with the CDN URL
    // Then store that URL into the DB as a message. Once that is done, then 
    // Broadcast the message to said room. 

    if ($request->has('upload')) {
        $files = $request->get('photo');
    
        $urls = [];
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = 'files/' . $file['name'];
    
            // Upload File to s3
            Storage::disk('digitalocean')->put($filename, $file['blob']);
            Storage::disk('digitalocean')->setVisibility($filename, 'public');
    
            $url = Storage::disk('digitalocean')->url($filename);
            $urls[] = $url;
        }
    
        return response()->json(['urls' => $urls]);
    }

    // broadcast(new NewChatMessage($newMessage))->toOthers();

    // return $newMessage;
}
```

First: I want to state that if there is something wrong with the current code, just know its because ive been playing around with this for 3 hours now and been trying anything. I am sure at one point I had it close but somehow screwed it up along the way so I am more looking for fresh eyes to show me my error.

That being said, the other part to take into account is in DevTools under Network I can clearly see the blob and can load it up, I can also see the "upload" item and under there the form data which shows the following

```
------WebKitFormBoundary7qD7xdmiQO9U1Ko0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="6A8B48B4-F546-438E-852E-C24340525C20_1_201_a.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary7qD7xdmiQO9U1Ko0--
```

it clearly also shows `photo: (binary)` so I am completely confused as to what I am doing wrong. The ULTIMATE goal here is to get the image, store it as public in S3/DigitalOcean then grab the public URL to the file and store in the DB.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I don't see a problem statement here. What errors or problems are you encountering, and what have you tried to solve them?

Comment: the Laravel code isnt finding the image in the blob so it isnt storing anything in the bucket.